# Github blocking on push to remote

Tags: git, github

I have installed LFS on my computer. Blocked here, push failed:

```
git push -u origin master

Uploading LFS objects:   6% (100/1753), 174 MB | 1.7 MB/s
```

Comment: Is this a repo you own or one you've forked? The `git push` is just not completing?

Comment: It's my own repo. I have performed those instructions as follows:
1.git  init
2.git add .
3.git commit -m "xxx"
4.git remote add origin [the url of my remote repo's ]
5.git push -u origin master

Yes! The git push is still blocking  without anything wrong.
Do I need to setup other settings ?

Comment: The repo's content is sourcecode of Elasticsearch v7.8.0. I want to research principle of Elasticsearch.^_^

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"? Your `git push` is starting with the upload-LFS-files-to-LFS-server step; depending on how big these large files are, and what the limit on transfer speed is, this could potentially take many hours. Note that even if you personally have a 1 Tbit/s network link, the LFS server might only allow data to flow in at 100 kbit/s to keep their own bandwidth usage down. (We can see from the above that at this point it has been averaging 1.7 MB/s.)

Comment: - The output details like as follows last night:

1. Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1753/1753), 1.4 GB | 0 B/s, done
2. Enumerating objects: 55252, done.
3. Counting objects: 100% (55252/55252), done.
4. error: RPC failed; curl 7 Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
5. fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly6 MiB | 20.41 MiB/s
6. Writing objects: 100% (55252/55252), 1.00 GiB | 37.14 MiB/s, done.
7. Total 55252 (delta 0), reused 51048 (delta 0)
8. fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
9. Everything up-to-date

Comment: The message starts with `Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1753/1753), 1.4 GB` <<< I think you've checked in WAAAAAY more files than you intended. You need to start fresh in a new folder and make sure you're restricting your repo to code and not data or other files.